# Issues with scaling html to fit content

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

Here is the link to the codepen: https://codepen.io/asosnovsky/pen/eYZmroJ

I feel like this might just be a strange edge case of how the browser renders content (either that or I am going nuts not being able to figure out what's going on).

**The Issue**:

I am trying to fit my content into two boxes using flex-css, but whenever the width of the device is below 800px, the right box overflows. The issue goes away when I remove the "span" elements that are inside the right box, but I can't figure out what exactly is causing the overflow.

In the codepen above, I added a complete example of my code.

**Some pictures**

It overall looks like this (incorrect)
[image]

But should be like this (regardless of screen size)

[image]

Thank you for all the help in advance!

**SCSS**

```css
#lobby {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#lobby-inner-wrap {
  padding: 5px;
  width: calc(100% - 5px);;
  height: calc(100% - 5px);
      #lobby-inner {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: row;
          #lobby-players {
              max-width: 100%;
              &--inner {
                  height: 100%;
                  margin: 5px;
                  padding: 5px;
                  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #0005;
              }
              max-width: 40vw;
              min-width: 150px;
              width: 200px;
              &--list {
                  overflow: auto;
              }
          }
          #lobby-settings {
              flex: 1;
              max-width: 100%;
              &--inner {
                  overflow: auto;
              }
              &--inner-wrap {
                  height: 100%;
                  box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px #0005;
                  padding: 5px;
                  margin: 5px;
                  overflow: hidden;
              }
          }
      }
}

.game-piece-hub {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: hidden;
    &--container {
        flex: 1;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        overflow-x: auto;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        .game-piece {
            flex: 0 0 150px;
            margin-left: 5px;
            margin-right: 5px;
        }
    }
}

$border-radius: 5%;
.game-piece {
    color: #ff3366;
    background-color: #212121;
    width: fit-content;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 4px #777a;
    border-top-left-radius: $border-radius;
    border-top-right-radius: $border-radius;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    &--inner {
        border-top-left-radius: $border-radius;
        border-top-right-radius: $border-radius;
        justify-content: center;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        overflow: hidden;
        // max-width: 200px;
        width: fit-content;
    }
    &--highlight {
        border-top-left-radius: $border-radius;
        border-top-right-radius: $border-radius;
        transition: opacity ease 500ms;
        opacity: 0;
        position: absolute;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        background: #63636399;
        font-size: 10em;
        color: #f58a;
        text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #fff5;
        &:hover {
            opacity: 0.5;
            background-color: #68526299;
        }
        &.enabled {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    }
    &--img {
        border-top-left-radius: $border-radius;
        border-top-right-radius: $border-radius;
        img {
            max-width: 100%;
        }
    }
    &--description {
        &--wrap {
            padding: 0;
            white-space: nowrap;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
        }
        background-color: #363636;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        .game-piece--name {
            margin-bottom: 0.25em;
            margin-top: 0.5em;
            font-size: 1em;
            text-align: center;
            max-height: 1.25em;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .game-piece--type {
            font-size: 0.75em;
            margin-bottom: 1em;
            color: black;
            background-color: #68caa4;
            padding: 0.5em;
            border-radius: 4px;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Add `min-width: 0;` to your `#lobby-settings` element. Technical details: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox/#min-size-auto

Comment: thank you!!!!! Can you make a proper "answer" and I will mark it!
:)
You have no idea how much time I killed trying to figure this out!